# display parent menu name and corresponding sub menu name in the sub menu pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I created parent and sub menus in word press.
Parent menus are custom links and don't have pages.
Sub menus are pages.
The menus are displayed in header area horizontally.
On hover the sub menus are displaying.
when clicking the sub menu,the corresponding page opens.
On that page i need to display corresponding parent menu and siblings of sub menu in left side of the page.

On the "About Us" page, the left-side navigation has been created manually.

[image: about us - created by default]

I'd like to have similar submenus on other parts of website, too (About NDT, Membership etc.). How can I achieve that?
For example, this is About NDT section - note that on the left side we have "About Us" contents.

What I need is to have "About NDT" contents there - as annotated on image.

[image: my webpage]

thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is there code you can paste? Screenshot? 
I don't know Wordpress but if you want to increase your chances of getting a helpful answer, please provide more details.

Comment: i am unable to add screenshots because your site not allowed for beginers

Comment: If you provide a link to relevant screenshot(s) here in comment section, I or someone else should be able to edit your post. Please provide such a link.

Comment: http://www.isnt.org.in/beta/ndt-basics/#aboutndt

Comment: on that page submenus showing left side of the page was default added..you may check by clicking other parent group sub pages..

Comment: I added two images and a short commentary. My edit seems to be waiting for peer-review to be accepted. I'm leaving the site now. Good luck.